# Ignore margins and wrap text when adding pictures in Latex

Tags: latex, tikz

I would like to add images in the top left/right or bottom left/right in a two-column page while ignoring the margins and having the text wrap around the picture. How can I also extend the solution to include half page images while ignoring the margins and with text wrapping.

I tried tikz package, but the text doesn't wrap around even when I use the wrapfig package.

For example, this is the code I used to insert image on the top left side of the page:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=1pt]%
            at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{example.jpg}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

This results in the picture at the desired position, but the text is obscured behind the image. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very pretty, but does the job I think (using geometry package only to get the correct values for top margin):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture} [remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north west]%
            at (current page.north west)
            {\includegraphics[width=0.46\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{example.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace*{\dimexpr(0.5\paperheight-\voffset-1in-\headsep-\headheight)}
    
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image: text correctly wrapping around the image]